# Get data from another controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two controllers, get.php and insert.php. I am not sure how codeigniter works but i also have get_model.php and insert_model.php. I want to call a controller method from get.php in insert.php and process the data from there, but what i get in the end is some kind of object, which clearly has the data inside but i am not sure how to access it.

I tried inlcuding the code just for that one function and creating an object which i call the method from.

```php
<?php
class get extends CI_Controller {


  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('get_model');
  }

    public function get_mtb_kvadrants(){
      $rez = $this->get_model->get_mtb_kvadranti();
      //return array("data" => $rez);
      $this->load->view("json", array("data" => $rez)); 
      //return $rez;
    }
}
?>
```

```php
<?php

class get_model extends CI_Model {

  public function __construct() {
    $this->load->database();
  }
  public function get_mtb_kvadranti(){
    $this->db->from('mtb_kvadranti');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
  }

}
?>
```

the call in the insert.php

```php
    require_once('/var/www/website/backend/get.php'); //include controller
    $aObj = new get();  //create object 
    $aObj->get_mtb_kvadrants(); //call function
    var_dump($aObj);
```

I get a large amount of stuff but this is the crucial one, this is one object which i get, otherwise there are alot more referenced objects inside from codeigniter :

```
 &object(CI_Loader)#14 (25) {
   ["_ci_ob_level":protected]=>
   int(1)
   ["_ci_view_paths":protected]=>
   array(1) {
     ["/var/www/website/backend/application/views/"]=>
     bool(true)
   }
   ["_ci_library_paths":protected]=>
   array(2) {
     [0]=>
     string(57) "/var/www/website/backend/application/"
     [1]=>
     string(73) "/var/www/website/vendor/codeigniter/framework/system/"
   }
   ["_ci_model_paths":protected]=>
   array(1) {
     [0]=>
     string(57) "/var/www/website/backend/application/"
   }
   ["_ci_helper_paths":protected]=>
   array(2) {
     [0]=>
     string(57) "/var/www/website/backend/application/"
     [1]=>
     string(73) "/var/www/website/vendor/codeigniter/framework/system/"
   }
   ["_ci_cached_vars":protected]=>
   array(1) {
     ["data"]=>
           array(666) {
       [0]=>
       array(2) {
         ["id"]=>
         string(1) "2"
         ["kvadrant"]=>
         string(6) "0046/2"
       }
       [1]=>
       array(2) {
         ["id"]=>
         string(1) "3"
         ["kvadrant"]=>
         string(6) "0047/1"
       }
       [2]=>
       array(2) {
         ["id"]=>
         string(1) "4"
         ["kvadrant"]=>
         string(6) "0047/2"
       }`
```

What i'd like to get is an array at the end which i can process in insert.php

Comment: If you have methods that you need to be able to access from multiple controllers, then those methods should rather be placed outside of the controllers, like in services, models, libraries or what they call it in CodeIgniter. A controller should only take a request and then call the correct methods on the correct classes and return the response. A controller (in my opinion) shouldn't contain any business logic or database queries directly,.

Comment: It's better for a controller to follow the [single-responsibility-principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) rule to prevent tightly-coupled codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the built-in Codeigniter [get_vars()](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L580) public method that allows you to read the value of `_ci_cached_vars` :

```
var_dump($aObj->load->get_vars());
```

Or [get_var()](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L566) if using a key :

```
var_dump($aObj->load->get_var('data'));
```

Answer (score 0):

***You cannot call one controller from another!*** CodeIgniter does not work that way.

It seems that you have two models - one for "get" and one for "insert". You should have one model with two methods, e.g. `get()` and `insert()`. You load that model in any controller where you need either method.

Comment: i will take this into account when refactoring the code. thank you. but yes, i've seen comments that codeigniter does not work this way.